# How do I select all links on page that contain a certain word?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I select all links on a page that contain a certain keyword. I want all links that contain 'amazon' in the link. Some links might be https, or http so I can't do it like so

```
let amazonLinks = document.querySelectorAll('[href*="https://www.amazon"]');
```

Comment: const amazonLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="amazon"]')

Answer (score 5):

you can pick all the links in the page using the below selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="amazon"]').forEach(function(a){
console.log(a.href)});
```

Cheers! hope this helps...

Answer (score 4):

Here are the wildcards for the querySelector:

`[attr^='someValue']` will match all ids starting with someId.

`[attr$='someValue']` will match all ids ending with someId.

`[attr*='someValue']` will match all ids containing someId.

If you need either `http` or `https` you should query as `://amazon.com`

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery :

```
$('a[href*="/YOUR-TEXT-HERE/"]').attr('href')
```